# Радиокнопки выделяются одновременно, чего не должно быть (jQuery)

Tags: html, jquery, ajax

> При переходе на jQuery перестала работать отмена выделения радиокнопки, если нажимается другая.
>   Выделяться должна **только одна** кнопка.
>
> У радиокнопки в каждой строке - генерируются уникальные имена.
>
> Ранее (когда таблица передавалась на клиента, как полностью html), эта функция работала.
>
> Теперь, когда таблица рисуется с помощью jQuery. а данные получаются из ajax-запроса, функция выделения только одной кнопки - **перестала работать.**

```js
/* выбирается только один checkbox или radio-кнопка*/
$(function() {
  $("table input:radio, table input:checkbox").click(function() {
    if ($(this).data('flag') === false) {
      $('table input:radio, table input:checkbox').prop('checked',
        false).data('flag', false);
      $(this).prop('checked', true).data('flag', true);
    } else {
      $(this).prop('checked', false).data('flag', false);
    }
  });
});

function addEmploye(employe) {
  var employeList = $("#table_list").find("tbody:last");

  var idCol = "<td>" + employe.id + "</td>";
  var emailCol = "<td>" + employe.email + "</td>";
  var passwordCol = "<td>" + employe.password + "</td>";
  var salaryCol = "<td>" + employe.salary + "</td>";

  var btn = "<input type='radio' name='myRadio_" + employe.id + "'      

  id = 'myRadio_" + employe.id + "' > ";

  var inputRadio = "<input class='radioClass' type='radio' name=" +
    employe.id + " data-flag=\"false\"/>";
  var iTag = "<i></i>";
  var labelForRadioLeft = "<label 


  onMouseDown = \"this.firstElementChild.isChecked=this.firstElementChild.
  checked;\
  "" +

  "onClick=\"this.firstElementChild.checked=!this.firstElementChild.
  isChecked;\
  ">";
  var labelForRadioRight = "</label>";
  var radio = "<td><div class='editClass'>" + labelForRadioLeft +
    inputRadio + iTag + labelForRadioRight +
    "</label></div></td>";

  var actionCol = "<td>" + btn + "</td>";

  var employeRow = "<tr>" + idCol + emailCol + passwordCol + salaryCol +
    /*actionCol*/
    radio + "</tr>";

  employeList.append(employeRow);
}
```

```css
/* обозначаем блок - флексом,
и указываем, что элементы внутри блока,
должны распологаться по центру.
*/

.editClass {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}


/* Свойство display отвечает за вывод и 
визуальное отображение элементов на странице.
Так как любой html-элемент генерирует на веб-странице
прямоугольный контейнер, укажем, что элемент не генерирует 
никакой контейнер, полностью удаляясь со страницы.
*/

.radioClass {
  vertical-align: top;
  /* управляет вертикальным выравниванием 
  строчных элементов и содержимого ячеек таблицы.*/
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  display: none;
  /* элемент с "видом по умолчанию", исключается 
  из общего потока, он не отображается на экране
  и под него не резервируется место на странице*/
}


/* рисуем радио-кнопку */

i {
  display: inline-block;
  /* Элемент генерирует строковый блок. */
  width: 20px;
  /* размеры */
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /* получаем круглый элемент */
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/* вид элемента до и после включения */

i:after,
i:before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  /* заполенение элемента на 100 % */
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: transform .5s;
  /* transition применяется для плавного изменения
  вида элемента при наведении на него курсора */
  border-radius: 50%;
}


/* цвет после нажатия */

i:after {
  background: green;
}


/* цвет перед нажатием */

i:before {
  background: #FFFF66;
}


/* поведение изменения цвета кнопки после того,
 как было снято выделение данной кнопки */

.radioClass:not(:checked)+i:after {
  transform: scale(0);
  /* для горизонтального масштабирования и для вертикального,
  0 - checkbox - постепенно теряет цвет и становится внутри с
  обычным фоном */
}


/* поведение изменения цвета кнопки после 
того, как была выделена данная кнопка */

.radioClass:checked+i:after {
  transform: scale(1);
  /* checkbox - заполняется цветом */
}


/* для скрипта, который фокусируется на последней странице в столбце. */

.changeColor {
  border: 3px solid red;
}


/* информационное сообщение на странице редактирования */

.choice {
  padding-top: 25px;
  padding-left: 25px;
  padding-bottom: 25px;
  color: red;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<h1>Список сотрудников</h1>
<table id="table_list">
  <tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>Email</th>
    <th>Пароль</th>
    <th>Заработная плата</th>
    <th>Операции</th>
  </tr>
  <tbody id="table_body">
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

> Чтобы можно было выбрать только одну радио кнопку из группы у них должен быть одинаковый name

**Внимательно** прочитайте вопрос.
 Кнопки должны быть уникальными, если вас смущает слово **радиокнопка**, то там может быть **checkbox**

Есть функция которая ранее работала на обычной html, которая позоволяла даже при уникальных именах, выбрать только одну радиокнопку.

Теперь данная функция сломалась.

Comment: Чтобы можно было выбрать только одну радио кнопку из группы у них должен быть одинаковый name

Answer (score 0):

> данные получаются из ajax-запроса

Хрестоматийный случай. Когда назначается обработчик `click`, кнопок на странице еще нет, и выборка `$("table input:radio, table input:checkbox")` - пустая.

Делегирование обработки события:

```
$("table").on("click", "input:radio, input:checkbox", function() {
  if ($(this).data('flag') === false) {
    $(this).closest('table').find('input:radio, input:checkbox').
      prop('checked', false).data('flag', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true).data('flag', true);
  } else {
    $(this).prop('checked', false).data('flag', false);
  }
});
```